# legend color spyder plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

From the following sample dataset:

```
df_toy = pd.DataFrame({"Group":[1,2],
                   "Var1":[100,20],
                   "Var2":[50,40],
                   "Var3":[10,14],
                   "Var4":[10,140],
                   "Var5":[100,14]})
```

I am plotting a spyder/polar plot by means of the following code:

```
variables = [col for col in df_toy.columns if col != "Group"]
labels= variables + [variables[0]]

np.random.seed(1)
angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, len(variables), endpoint=False)

# The first value is repeated to close the chart.
angles=np.concatenate((angles, [angles[0]]))

# polar plot each row separately
for row in df_toy.values.tolist():
    values = row[1:] + [row[1]]
    plt.polar(angles, values, 'o-', linewidth=2)
    plt.fill(angles, values, alpha=0.25)

# Representation of the spider graph
plt.legend(df_toy["Group"])
plt.thetagrids(angles * 180 / np.pi, labels)
plt.show()
```

which produces the following plot, However, there is a wrong correspondence between legend and line color:

[image]

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the legend entries while plotting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
...
# polar plot each row separately
for row in df_toy.values.tolist():
    values = row[1:] + [row[1]]
    plt.polar(angles, values, 'o-', linewidth=2, label=row[0])
    plt.fill(angles, values, alpha=0.25)

# Representation of the spider graph
plt.legend()
...
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution skip the unexpected behaviour of my code. thanks a lot

Comment: I would rather set Group as the index of the dataframe, so, you don't have to filter it constantly out from your values. But maybe there are reasons for your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't reproduce your issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_toy = pd.DataFrame({"Group":[1,2],
                   "Var1":[100,20],
                   "Var2":[50,40],
                   "Var3":[10,14],
                   "Var4":[10,140],
                   "Var5":[100,14]})

variables = [col for col in df_toy.columns if col != "Group"]
labels= variables + [variables[0]]

np.random.seed(1)
angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, len(variables), endpoint=False)

# The first value is repeated to close the chart.
angles=np.concatenate((angles, [angles[0]]))

# polar plot each row separately
for row in df_toy.values.tolist():
    values = row[1:] + [row[1]]
    plt.polar(angles, values, 'o-', linewidth=2)
    plt.fill(angles, values, alpha=0.25)

# Representation of the spider graph
plt.legend(df_toy["Group"])
plt.thetagrids(angles * 180 / np.pi, labels)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image: polar plot]

Comment: Strange, I can reproduce the OPs output.

Comment: Something weird with the environment should be happening, my matplotlib version is 3.5.1, not sure if also could about this.

Comment: Anyway, better define the labels as showed by @Mr.T